# How to extend a jython class in a java class

Tags: java, jython

I would like to extend a jython class in a java class

```
public class JavaClass extends JythonClass
```

how do I import the Jython class? Does it have to be compiled? A link to documentation would be already useful.

Example:

```
class JythonClass(threading.Thread):
def do(self):
    print("hallo")
```

--

```
public class JavaClass extends JythonClass
{
    public void hello()
    { System.out.print("hallo")}
}
```

Comment: Extending classes in Java accomplishes two separate things: (1) making the subclass support the same interfaces as the superclass (is-a relationship), and (2) providing default implementations of those interfaces. Do you really need both (or either) of these things? A Jython class is not going to have any real "type"s aside from any Java class or interface it, itself, extends. For (2), you could always use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: You might get closest to "extending a Jython class" by "extending" a Jython *object* with a [dynamic proxy class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), but that might be overkill for what your real needs are?

Comment: http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/10/jython-inheritance-java.html
This might be what you need

Comment: @DanGetz, thats the best answer. Make it a seperate answer and I'll award (if nothing else comes up) to you

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about the dynamic proxy idea anymore. I think it might be more complicated than other solutions, and might have to depend on the internals of Jython.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extend a Jython class in Java such that the result is usable *in Jython* by creating a Jython class that extends both the Java "subclass" and the Jython "superclass". Let's say you have this Jython class:

```py
class JythonClass(object):
    def get_message(self):
        return 'hello'
    def print_message(self):
        print self.get_message()
```

You can create your Java class, partially, without extending anything:

```java
public class JavaClass {
    private String message;
    public String get_message() {
        return message;
    }
    protected JavaClass(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And then cause the "extending" relationship in Jython:

```py
from javapackage import JavaClass as _JavaClass
from jythonpackage import JythonClass

class JavaClass(_JavaClass, JythonClass):
    pass
```

Now this will work:

```py
obj = JavaClass('goodbye')
obj.print_message()
```

If instead you wish to extend a Jython class in Java, and use it like a normal Java class, the easiest way would be to use composition, instead of inheritance:

- create a Java interface for the methods on your Jython class
- make your Jython class extend the Java interface (either by directly modifying your Jython class code, or by something like what I explained above)
- create your Java subclass as implementing the interface, with an instance of the Jython "superclass" as a private field
- any method in your Java subclass that you don't wish to override, just call that method on the private Jython instance

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is covered by [Ch10 of The Definitive Guide to Jython](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#using-jython-within-java-applications)

In this example the author uses an interface `BuildingType` this can be changed to an abstract class

```
public abstract class BuildingType {
 public abstract String getBuildingName();
 public abstract String getBuildingAddress();
 public abstract String getBuildingId();

 @Override
 public String toString(){
   return "Abstract Building Info: " +
     getBuildingId() + " " +
     getBuildingName() + " " +
     getBuildingAddress();
  }
}
```

which you can extend with your own methods, in this case I have added `toString()` and used it in 'print' instead of the authors original code:

```
public class Main {

  private static void print(BuildingType building) {
      System.out.println(building.toString());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      BuildingFactory factory = new BuildingFactory();
      BuildingType building1  =  factory.create("BUILDING-A", "100 WEST MAIN", "1")
      print(building1);
      BuildingType building2 = factory.create("BUILDING-B", "110 WEST MAIN", "2");
      print(building2);
      BuildingType building3 = factory.create("BUILDING-C", "120 WEST MAIN", "3");
      print(building3);
  }

}
```

You can duplicate this code using the code from CH10 of the The Definitive Guide to Jython and all credit must go to the author - I've only changed the `Interface` into a `Abstract` class.

You coluld also consider using a [Java 7 Default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) method in the interface